# How to use laravel pagination with filter

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I have `getCanSeeAttribute` function in post model, and I try to get posts with pagination using `filter()`

```
$posts = Post::where(function ($query1) use ($users) {
            $query1->where('posted_type', 'user')->whereIn('posted_id', $users);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query2) use ($stores) {
            $query2->where('posted_type', 'store')->whereIn('posted_id', $stores);
        })
        ->with('likes', 'postable')
        ->withCount('comments', 'likes')
        ->latest()->paginate($paginate)->filter(function($post){
            return $post->can_see == true;
        });
```

The problem is when I use filter, it gets data attribute only, but I need all pagination attributes.

```
first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/timeline?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 1,
"last_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/timeline?page=1",
"next_page_url": null,
"path": "http://localhost:8000/api/timeline",
"per_page": 10,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 6,
"total": 6
```

**can_see not column in table it is Accessor**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope you know what are you doing. Assuming you need to get results that has `can_see` field set to true, you should rather use:

```
$posts = Post::where('can_see', true)
         ->where(function($q) {
            $q->where(function ($query1) use ($users) {
              $query1->where('posted_type', 'user')->whereIn('posted_id', $users);
            })->orWhere(function ($query2) use ($stores) {
               $query2->where('posted_type', 'store')->whereIn('posted_id', $stores);
            })
        })->with('likes', 'postable')
        ->withCount('comments', 'likes')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

As you see I additionally wrapped (where .. orWhere) in additional `where` closure to make sure valid query will be generated.

Otherwise you should use:

```
$posts = Post::where(function($q) {
            $q->where(function ($query1) use ($users) {
              $query1->where('posted_type', 'user')->whereIn('posted_id', $users);
            })->orWhere(function ($query2) use ($stores) {
               $query2->where('posted_type', 'store')->whereIn('posted_id', $stores);
            })
        })->with('likes', 'postable')
        ->withCount('comments', 'likes')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate($paginate);

$posts = $posts->setCollection($posts->getCollection()->filter(function($post){
        return $post->can_see == true;
   })
);
```

However it's very unlikely the 2nd way is better one in your case. Assuming you have 1 mln of matching records and then of them has `can_see` set to true, and the rest have it set to false, it would cause that you will get 1 mln of records from database and then you will filter only 10 of them what would be performance killer for your application.

Comment: can_see not column in posts table so i use filter()

Comment: Ok, so this can be the use case, however assuming you will have many records it will cause performance problem, so if it's based on some permissions, probably you should then move them to database to get posts user has permission from database without filtering on PHP side.

Comment: but in my case "can_see" based on (friends , followers , all) , so is there way to put permissions in database

Comment: @hossamGamal So in such case, you can use 2nd solution I showed

Answer (score 0):

You can add this following code, define after `$post`

```
$post->appends($request->only('posted_type'));
```